# Incrementing counter inside list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I wrote a function that will list all non consecutive integers on a list and their indices, it works but I'm wondering whether it is possible to make it into one-liner. My original code looks like this:

```
def all_non_consecutive(arr):
  result = []
  i = 1
  for num in arr[1:]:
      if arr[i-1] != num -1:
          result.append({'i': arr.index(num), 'n':  num})
      i += 1
  return result
```

What I'm trying is this:

```
def all_non_consecutive(arr):
  result = []
  i= 1
  return [{'i': arr.index(num), 'n':  num} for num in arr[1:] if num - 1 != arr[i-1]]
```

But as you can see there's nothing to increment i so the code doesn't work. Is there a way to make the list comprehension increment outside variable?

Comment: Your first solution may not work as you would expect if the list contains some duplicate elements. As for the list comprehension, there is no way you can increment a variable outside.

Comment: @Austin Sounds like you didn't get [the memo](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/).

Comment: @superbrain how exactly would you use that here?

Comment: @Tomerikoo I wouldn't. But you could replace the `arr[i-1]]` with `arr[(i:=i+1)-2]`.

Comment: @superbrain, replacing arr[i-1] with arr[(i:=i+1)-2] in my code results in syntax error

Comment: @JanKowalski Well then update to Python 3.8 :-)

Comment: @superb rain What does := operator do? I cannot find anything about it

Comment: @JanKowalski How is it possible that you can't find anything about it? I linked to it.

Comment: Oh, I missed it. Still though, I don't understand it, it's too technical and waaaaaaaaaaay too long. But in the meantime I found much better explanation someplace else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterating directly over the list, you can iterate over range(1, len(arr)).

```py
def all_non_consecutive1(arr):
  result = []
  i = 1
  for i in range(1, len(arr)):
      if arr[i-1] != arr[i] - 1:
          result.append({'i': i, 'n':  arr[i]})
  return result
```

As list comprehension.

```py
def all_non_consecutive2(arr):
  return [{'i': i, 'n':  arr[i]} for i in range(1, len(arr)) if arr[i-1] != arr[i] - 1]
```

Comment: None of those solutions work, they just return. Both gi\/e me the same result for list [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10]. Return looks like this:

[{'i': 0, 'n': 1}, {'i': 1, 'n': 2}, {'i': 2, 'n': 3}, {'i': 3, 'n': 4}, {'i': 4, 'n': 6}, {'i': 5, 'n': 7}, {'i': 6, 'n': 8}, {'i': 7, 'n': 10}]

Comment: @JanKowalski I misunderstand your question, now it should be fine. If now, please state expected result.