# increment a counter using list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

So I was solving a problem that wanted me to find out the number of times a sublist has occurred in a given list.

```
def count_sublist_occurrence(sublst, lst):

    """
    Input : non-empty list (sublst) and list (lst)
    Output: the number of times sublst occurs in lst
    For example:
    >>> count_sublist_occurrence([1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])
    2
    """

counter = 0

for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i : len(sublst) + i] == sublst:
        counter += 1

return counter
```

It is not required to shorten the list but I decided to give it a try anyway.
I tried to shorten it with list comprehension and I wrote something like this

```
counter for i in range(len(lst)) if lst[i : len(sublst) + 1] == sublst #counter += 1
```

This code is obviously wrong as I don't know how to increment the counter inside a list comprehension.

Is there a way for me to code this?

Comment: refer here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63438270/incrementing-counter-inside-list-comprehension/63438448

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - keeping counter inside list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27778604/python-keeping-counter-inside-list-comprehension)

Comment: How about using `sum`? `sum(lst[i:i+len(sublst)] == sublst for i in range(len(lst)))` or sth like that.

Comment: or you can also convert the lists to strings and use `.count`: `return ''.join(map(str, lst)).count(''.join(map(str, sublst)))`